# Do other programming languages/platforms problem with Garbage Collector like JVM?

Tags: php, .net, ruby, garbage-collection, jvm

i just want to know whether other programming languages/platforms like PHP, Ruby, C# etc. (where you dont have to manually deal with memory-managment) have the same prolem with GC like Java on JVM which results in long pause, high response time, low throughput etc. on large heap size (> 5gb)?

Or that's a general problem with all languages/platforms with GC-Ability, but it is in java-world a hot discussion thema just because there are many large scale systems are written in Java out there and one oftener have to deal with this problem then elsewhere?

Thx you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, all GC-based languages will have similar issues with very large heaps. It has very little to do with the language, and everything with the VM implementation (as well as GC tuning options and of course the application code). Since applications with very large heaps are still quite rare but becoming more common, this is becoming a major selling point for vendors of alternative VM implementations, such as IBM or [Azul Systems](http://www.azulsystems.com/solutions/java-scalability-overview).

Comment: thx you, that's the ack. i want to hear from the community. Ok, this prolem is not java-specific. But only Java has solution thank Azul Zing JVM. Im happy being java-developer! :-D

Comment: @tunggad: I wouldn't say that only Java has a solution (or that only Azul has a solution for Java). It's a hot research topic, and improvements are made all the time in various places.

Comment: @tunggad: And even *if* Azul were the only people on the planet who have the answer, hey, Ruby runs on the JVM, and so do PHP, Python, Lisp, Scheme, Smalltalk, ECMAScript, and about 400 other languages, even C and x86 (and MIPS) binary code.

Comment: yikes o_o "Zing Platform allows each instance to scale to hundreds of GBs of heap memory and tens of cores seamlessly and elastically."

Answer (score 0):

Speaking for .NET, no. Garbage collection happens automatically and in most cases it's not something you need to worry about as the managed heap is continually monitored and collection is performed as needed.

However if you do require some control over garbage collection, you can [control the latency mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384202.aspx) and have a [measure of control over inducing collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384155.aspx).

On a related topic, you CAN still have memory leaks, even in managed code. If that is the case, it won't matter how often the garbage collector fires or how efficient it is...

Comment: that means, .NET programms can run on 100GB and more large heap without any significant negative impact on performance (response time, throughput) due to GC?  Of course im not talking about memory-leak, i know, that one can still have memory-leak even with GC.

Comment: So... run any apps with a 100GB heap lately?

Comment: Haha, I thought we were talking >5GB...not 100GB. I have no experience with heaps that large. I suspect any language would have some level of issues with that size.

Comment: It happens, and it is becoming common as memory becomes more common. While MongoDB is a database and not an application, just as an illustration, Foursquare stores their ~64GB database shards entirely in memory on the shards' host nodes.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to with the programming language. It's a question of the quality of the garbage collector implementation.

Realtime garbage collectors with predictable and tunable pause times times have been known since the 1970s. Nowadays, it gets even easier: as machines routinely have 1000s of CPUs, just set a couple dozen or so aside for the garbage collector to run on, and do the collection concurrently.

The Azul Jaca Compute Appliance, for example, does exactly that. It is specifically designed for very large applications with very large heaps and near-realtime requirements (e.g. automated trading systems for hedgefonds). And since the JCA runs a JVM, and both Ruby and PHP (and Python, Smalltalk, Lisp, Scheme, JAvaScript, …) run on the JVM, they get access to that technology as well.

The current version (JCA 7300) has up to 864 CPUs and 768 GiByte of RAM. Typically, the grbage collector(s) will use 20–30 CPUs, leaving well over 700 (the JIT compiler also uses a dozen or three) for the application(s). That's still way more than almost all applications can handle.

Comment: Haha, that says, if other languages want to have the strenght like Java they would need to move on JVM ^^. thx you!

Comment: @tunggad: You don't *have* to use the JVM. There are plenty of good Smalltalk and Lisp VMs, for example, that have good GCs. Also, GCs tend to be pretty agnostic. The .NET GC, for example, does not know anything about the .NET type system, .NET bytecode or anything else for that matter. The only thing it knows is how to find out which objects another object references. It's simple economics, really: you *could* spend a billion dollars, a hundred engineers, a thousand man-years and a dozen PhDs and develop your own GC &hellip; or you could just get a free ride off Oracle.

Comment: @tunggad: As Charles Oliver Nutter, one of the lead developers of JRuby, likes to point out: there are more people working on just one of Oracle's 7 garbage collectors than there are people working on all Ruby implementations combined.

Comment: Do some languages have properties that make it harder to garbage collect than others? And I don't know what joke to make about Charles' comment: that Ruby is less important than Oracle's garbage, or that Oracle is [very good](http://www.zdnet.com/news/oracle-ms-flap-how-it-happened/96149) at garbage collection!